# how to start iPhone charging from sleeping MacBook

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, charging

When I connect my **iPhone 7** (iOS 12.4.1) to my **MacBook Pro** (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) (macOS Mojave 10.14.6),

it seems like the iPhone doesn't start charging until after

- the MacBook is unlocked (by waking it and inputting the password)
- the iPhone is unlocked (passcode/touchID entered).

---

Imagine my MacBook is lying, lid-closed, on the desk.

If I connect my iPhone to it via the USB cable, I want it to start charging.

I don't want to have to do anything else.

How can I configure my devices so that this is possible?

Comment: Is your MacBook connected to a power source when you do this?

Comment: @NimeshNeema yes and no